# Is this inequality property true?

Tags: abstract-algebra, inequality, induction, natural-numbers

I'm having some trouble defining weather this inequality is true or not...

Basically, I wanted to know if its true that

> if $a \geq b$ and $c \geq d \Rightarrow a + c \geq b + d$

Well, basically I just wanted to know if this implication is true:

> $n(4n^2 + 42n + 120) + 50 \geq n(n^2 + 13n + 38) + 36$,  $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$
>
> Because $50 \geq 36 \Rightarrow n(4n^2+42n+120) \geq n(n^2+13n+38) $

Is this implication really true?

Thanks!

Comment: My mistake.. I've edited the first inequality. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By definition $a + c \geq b + d\iff a+c-b-d\ge 0\iff (a-b)+(c-d)\ge 0$, but the last expression is a sum of two non-negative entities, so indeed, $a + c \geq b + d$.

As to your implication, while it holds (truth implies truth is deducible in logic), the reasoning is off. You can't deduce from $a + c \geq b + d\& a\ge b$ that $c\ge d$ (there're obvious counterexamples), you need to use external arguments.

You can prove that$$
n(4n^2 + 42n + 120) + 50 \geq n(n^2 + 13n + 38) + 36$$ by comparing coefficients at different powers of $n$ and taking in account that $n\ge 0$.

Comment: That's why I added that all n where natural numbers... so, indeed, the removing the 50 and 36 out of the equation should maintain the inequality?

Comment: Hi, I can see your point.. is a one-way implication. That `a+c \geq b+d` not necessarily implies `c \geq d \Righarrow a \geq b`

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the implication is true. $$a\geq b\implies a+c\geq b+c$$ $$c\geq d\implies b+c \geq b+d$$

By transitivity, $$a+c\geq b+d$$