# Prove inequality by induction

Tags: algebra-precalculus, induction, natural-numbers

Once again, I'm stuck in a demonstration by induction, this time, it's really proving that an inequality is valid. So, here is the inequality:

> Prove that $\binom{2n}{n} \geq (n+5)^2 \ \forall n \geq 5, n \in \mathbb{N} $

Then, what I wanted to prove is that:

> $\binom{2n+2}{n+1} \geq (n+6)^2$

For $n=5$:

> $\binom{10}{5} = 252 \geq 100$

The inductive step would be:

> $\binom{2n+2}{n+1} \geq (n+6)^2$
>
> $\binom{2n+2}{n+1} = \frac{(2n + 2)(2n+1)(2n)!}{(n+1)(n+1)n!n!} = \frac{2(2n+1)}{n+1}\frac{(2n)!}{n!n!}$

By Inductive Hypothesis, I know that:

> $\frac{2(2n+1)}{n+1}\frac{(2n)!}{n!n!} \geq \frac{2(2n+1)}{n+1} (n+5)^2 $

I want to prove, indeed, that:

> $\frac{2(2n+1)}{n+1} (n+5)^2 \geq (n+6)^2$

And there I'm stuck. I've tried doing this:

> $ 2(2n+1)(n+5)^2) \geq (n+6)^2(n+1) $
>
> $\Rightarrow 4n^3 + 40 n^2 + 120 n + 50 \geq n^3 + 13n^2+38n+36$
>
> $\Rightarrow n(4n^2 + 42n + 120) + 50 \geq n(n^2 + 13n + 38) + 36$
>
> Because $50 \geq 36 \Rightarrow n(4n^2+42n+120) \geq n(n^2+13n+38) $

But they told me [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/443700/is-this-inequality-property-true) that this inequality is not necessarily true. So.. any ideas how should I follow?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: The first case is $n=5$, not $n=1$.

Comment: Now you have to replace $36$ with $(5+5)^2$ in the first case.

Comment: you're right.. in fact, I calculate it for n=5, I dont know why I type n=1.. must be the custom for common induction. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have is right, you want to show that if $n \geq 5$, then

$$2(2n+1)(n+5)^2 \geq (n+6)^2(n+1) $$

This can be shown in various ways. For example, if you just expand everything, you get that

$$2(2n+1)(n+5)^2 \geq (n+6)^2(n+1) \Leftrightarrow 3n^3 + 29n^2 + 72n + 14 \geq 0 $$

which is obviously true for the region that we want.

---

Note, what they are telling you, is that just because $50 \geq 36$, does not necessary imply that $2(2n+1)(n+5)^2 \geq (n+6)^2(n+1) $.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Any tip from where can I start to prove that inequality? So far, whatever I've tried, was not good for the proof.

Comment: @pmartelletti Just expand everything. Remember to use the fact that $n \geq 5$.

Comment: just as I did in the last few steps? I was not able to go anywhere with the expansion :S

Comment: @pmartelletti Yes, see my edit above.

Comment: Great, thanks for your response! I get it now.. thanks a lot!